# ASP.NET Core retry entire server-side request pipeline

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Due to intermittent failures I want to retry a request, without reusing stateful dependencies.

Is it possible to retry an entire request so that a new dependency scope will be generated and fresh object instances will be used?

I don't want to create a middleware if repeatedly invoking the next delegate uses the same resolved instances as the first time.

Comment: I couldn't understand your requirement clearly. Do you mean you want to send request from server-side to another resource or you want to retry the whole server-side pipeline?

Comment: Everything server-side. _I want to retry the request that I've received from the client_, i.e. possibly activate every middle-ware again after creating a new dependency scope